# django user queries to get data from database

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have models.py like this

```
class Faculty(TimeStampedModel):
    _registry = []
    faculty_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    current_subjects = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    research_interest = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    joining_year = models.CharField(
        max_length=5, )
    projects = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

now the user can't add Faculty but can view those created from the admin. In order to do so the user must enter the faculty_code in a form after which I have to get the other fields and show it to the user.
I don't how to implement this. I mean anytime we create a django-form and use POST method it creates a new object I don't want that. User should send a 'GET' request to fetch data of other fields of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a form is necessary for this, use a `DetailView`.

**url**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^faculty/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', FacultyDetail.as_view()),
)
```

**view**

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class FacultyDetail(DetailView):
    model = Faculty
    slug_field = 'faculty_code'
```

More info:

- [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView)
- [ccbv](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/)

Comment: this works but my professor wants to enter the code in a text-box to see the details.

Comment: You can still use a textbox, create a view with a textbox, and then use javascript to get the contents of the box and call the view I provided with the content as the slug.

Comment: thats exactly what i  don't know how to do.

Comment: I gave you a solution, figure out your homework for yourself, that's kind of the point of it.